# Make divs selectable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to create two selectable divs. The divs should behave like buttons. I want to be able to select one of the divs using left and right arrow. Until now I was able to implement this using this code

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownDocument, false);

function keyDownDocument(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;

  if(keyCode==37) {
  // left button
  $( ".left" ).addClass( "active_button" );
  $( ".right" ).removeClass( "active_button" );

  } else if(keyCode==39) {
 // right button
  $( ".right" ).addClass( "active_button" );
  $( ".left" ).removeClass( "active_button" );
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 width:100%;
  height: 160px;
 background-color: gray;
 padding-left: 90px;
 padding-right: 90px;
}

 #wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
} 

#text {
 padding-top: 33px;
 padding-bottom: 33px;
 width: 65%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 44px;
 float: left;
}
#buttons {
 padding-top: 45px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
.left {
 height: 70px; 
 width: 70px; 
 margin-right: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 
}
.right {
 height: 70px; 
 width: 70px;
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-block;
}

.active_button {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="text">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
 </div>
 <div id="buttons">
  <div   class="left active_button" >not ok</div>
  <div   class="right">ok</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to be able to interact with the buttons also with the mouse. I am not sure on how to proceed with that.

Comment: How do you want to interact with the buttons? Do you want a button which is clicked to be the selected button?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to add is

```
$('#buttons div').click(function(){
     $('#buttons div').removeClass('active_button');  // clear active button
     $(this).addClass('active_button');               // set current button to active

});
```

To toggle the active_button from both buttons.

```js
$('#buttons div').click(function(){
     $('#buttons div').removeClass('active_button');
     $(this).addClass('active_button');
     
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownDocument, false);

function keyDownDocument(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;

  if(keyCode==37) {
  // left button
  $( ".left" ).addClass( "active_button" );
  $( ".right" ).removeClass( "active_button" );

  } else if(keyCode==39) {
 // right button
  $( ".right" ).addClass( "active_button" );
  $( ".left" ).removeClass( "active_button" );
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 width:100%;
  height: 160px;
 background-color: gray;
 padding-left: 90px;
 padding-right: 90px;
}

 #wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
} 

#text {
 padding-top: 33px;
 padding-bottom: 33px;
 width: 65%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 44px;
 float: left;
}
#buttons {
 padding-top: 45px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
.left {
 height: 70px; 
 width: 70px; 
 margin-right: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 
}
.right {
 height: 70px; 
 width: 70px;
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-block;
}

.active_button {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="text">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
 </div>
 <div id="buttons">
  <div   class="left active_button" >not ok</div>
  <div   class="right">ok</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest extracting the selection code into 2 functions to avoid duplicating code.

Then you can simply call these functions on click of the buttons:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownDocument, false);

function selectLeft() {
  $( ".left" ).addClass( "active_button" );
  $( ".right" ).removeClass( "active_button" );
}

function selectRight() {
  $( ".right" ).addClass( "active_button" );
  $( ".left" ).removeClass( "active_button" );
}

function keyDownDocument(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;

  if(keyCode==37) {
    selectLeft();
  } else if(keyCode==39) {
    selectRight();
  }
}

$('.left').click(selectLeft);
$('.right').click(selectRight);
```

```css
#wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 width:100%;
  height: 160px;
 background-color: gray;
 padding-left: 90px;
 padding-right: 90px;
}

 #wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
} 

#text {
 padding-top: 33px;
 padding-bottom: 33px;
 width: 65%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 44px;
 float: left;
}
#buttons {
 padding-top: 45px;
 padding-bottom: 45px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

.left {
 height: 70px; 
 width: 70px; 
 margin-right: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 
}
.right {
 height: 70px; 
 width: 70px;
 background-color: white;
 display: inline-block;
}

.active_button {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="text">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard.
 </div>
 <div id="buttons">
  <div   class="left active_button" >not ok</div>
  <div   class="right">ok</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Selecting divs in a webpage

The standard way to select elements in html is setting them tabbable or set tabindex.
I don't know if all browser support selecting tabbable elements with the arrow keys.
All browser do support using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to select next element on a page.
And its sibling the <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> previous element selector.

This is the current standardized way to navigate a webapge. Implementing your own could conflict with this.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.showButton {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 48%;
}

.showButton:focus {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.showButton:active {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="showButton" tabindex="1"> Test </div>
  <div class="showButton" tabindex="2"> Test </div>
</div>
```